# Flutter reading from file returns Instance of Future<String> instead of the real text in the file

Tags: string, file, flutter, text, future

I want to read the data from a .txt file in FLutter, it contains just a number. I use the functions from the official documentations(https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files), of course modified them a bit to fit in my program:

```
class _InClassRoomState extends State<InClassRoom> {
  @override
  var pontsz = readpontok().toString();
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }
    Future<String> readpontok() async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Read the file.
    String contents = await file.readAsString();

    return await contents;
  } catch (e) {
    // If encountering an error, return 0.
    return null;
  }
}
```

The respecting part of my widget tree is the body of the Scaffold:

```
body: Center(
      child: Text(
        pontsz.toString(),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(

          fontSize: 50,
          color: Colors.black,


        ),


      ),

    ),
```

But when I run the code it just writes "Instance of Future in the body of the scaffold. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a Future to the string. you should call `readpontok()` from `initState()` and setState `pontsz = content`

```
class _InClassRoomState extends State<InClassRoom> {

  // create pontsz variable
  var pontsz;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // call the function
    readpontok();
  }


  Future readpontok() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file.
      String contents = await file.readAsString();
      setState(() {
        pontsz = contents;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, display Error
      setState(() {
        pontsz = "Error";
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!